# Sent data to webservice using json from a form field after it is encrypted to a cipher

Tags: php, json, web-services, encryption

Im creating a web  payment form.As according to pci I cant store a credit card number so i use a third party api for encrypting thr credit card number.According to that third party documentation,I have to add their script in my html form `<script type="text/javascript" src="./-client-2.1.2.js"></script>` and also to the form a unique value to the form

```
<input id="txtEncryptionKey" name="txtEncryptionKey" class="_encryptionkey"
        type="hidden" value="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvWpIQFjQQCPpaIlJKpeg
        irp5kLkzLB1AxHmnLk73D3TJbAGqr1QmlsWDBtMPMRpdzzUM7ZwX3kzhIuATV4Pe
        7RKp3nZlVmcrT0YCQXBrTwqZNh775z58GP2kZs+gVfNqBampJPzSB/hB62KkByhE
        Cn6grrRjiAVwJyZVEvs/********+aE16emtX12RgI5JdzdOiNyZEQteU6zRBRJE
        ocPWVxExaOpVVVJ5+UnW0LcalzA+lRGRTrQJ5JguAPiAOzRPTK/lYFFpCAl/F8wt
        oAVG1c8zO2NcQ0Pko+fmeidRFxJ/did2btV+9Mkze3mBphwFmvnxa35LF+Cs/XJH
        DwIDAQAB" />
```

and to the field I wish to encrypt Credit card number:

```
<input type="text" name="txtCreditCard" id="txtCreditCard" class="_data"
```

and also to the submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_process" value="Submit" id="btn_process" class="_submit btn btn-success">
```

and here is my entire code

```
 <html>   
    <head>
     <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./-client-2.1.2.js"></script>
    </head>   
    <body>   
        <h2>Data Collection</h2><p>

    <form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input id="txtEncryptionKey" name="txtEncryptionKey" class="encryptionkey"
    type="hidden" value="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvWpIQFjQQCPpaIlJKpeg
    irp5kLkzLB1AxHmnLk73D3TJbAGqr1QmlsWDBtMPMRpdzzUM7ZwX3kzhIuATV4Pe
    7RKp3nZlVmcrT0YCQXBrTwqZNh775z58GP2kZs+gVfNqBampJPzSB/hB62KkByhE
    Cn6grrRjiAVwJyZVEvs/2vrxaEpO+aE16emtX12RgI5JdzdOiNyZEQteU6zRBRJE
    ocPWVxExaOpVVVJ5+UnW0LcalzA+lRGRTrQJ5JguAPiAOzRPTK/lYFFpCAl/F8wt
    oAVG1c8zO2NcQ0Pko+fmeidRFxJ/did2btV+9Mkze3mBphwFmvnxa35LF+Cs/XJH
    DwIDAQAB" />
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Credit card number: <input type="text" name="credit" id="credit" class="_data"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn_process" value="Submit" id="btn_process" class="_submit btn btn-success">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

So what happens here is,my credit card number is taken by the javascript as soon as I click on submit and is converted into a cipher text in the page it self which returns a unique cipher text as something like this

```
_cipherText=EIQ4H1Tmmxb0wvyfX9HvbSg0SH0ez1GyZSZjQ8OQqKOI8wtY%2B06uq9XlsDSQdmvRtZtCwJv%2FFbo6xxQ4ClPQZN06nO%2BB8Hw3PddPFLqGtViOMCpBif9Tv0LXPy4%2FQ2L%2F5crTjVQa6WdoJABTgFlOcJ8x%2Bs%2FSSmR5Hd7R9SznfpJQp64IQ6FP%2F2ASxpU14YswgDvTumYZ%2BPElbdKG5u71snNWoQNUClWFn4d8yk6%2BaJ%2FDUGWqotpxchhOFvHMePXsdE8%2F2mGlmz5iiOSH5LlvHptenQMtTvHjBuwdMo4rnutjJ%2FRqaR3sWcndZIWYmEZ7OfA%3D%3D
```

Now usinng a php I need to store this cipher into a variable and sent it to a web service

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
function writeMsg()
{
echo "Hello world!";
}

//creates a token.
function Tokenize()
{
// see details here http:/.turnapi.com/docs/1.0/rest-tokenize
$_id = "763994532109974";
$api_key = "0za2fOfdWU8575BnTH";
$encrypted_data = "acAx/CwWGCURIhwf7gIw36TFmXoGFrFa5l9hCgcGEW4/mVQAAzZuT4XRjktb7XR0sAthHTuSPYegNYUy7g1stP+ypfVBcH0hNiI72N22yy3WYp0VUfAKDp33HBgUVQwg0TWAenRSNbUwC0Qv49E5bubYo4YBnERWi4JNLJZPlEQUfjMovvWQsQdFHd7U79XJZnZQdW92CKFDrTX8bCS4/n0LDEEVBILJGBnjnvKOQjQarsX8OuU6/73qpy36f9Gz3+X6IRfRhVbINNV0Seii6qSXT03NyvbERDsU/CiOrZ1tY0RuiKh4rsvCfPYrX2h67ZZ7nzrz0DeV+BYyo0e06A=="; 
// CC data to tokenize..

$data = array(
    'ID' =>_id,
    'APIKey' => $api_key,
    'EncryptedData' => $encrypted_data,
    'TokenScheme' => 4 
);
//convert to JSON
$json = json_encode($data);

 echo "Step1 done... ";
 echo $json;

//curl config
$url = 'https://test-api..com:8081/TokenServices.svc/REST/TokenizeFromEncryptedValue';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                    'Content-Type: application/json', //we are using json in this example, you could use xml as well
                                    'Content-Length: '.strlen($json),
                                    'Accept: application/json')       //we are using json in this example, you could use xml as well
                                    );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//call web service
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//decode result
$jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);

//handle result
if ($jsonResult['Success'] == FALSE)
{
    echo "Error Message: ";
    echo $jsonResult['Error'];
}
else
{
    echo "your token is: ";
    echo $jsonResult['Token'];
}
}

//writeMsg();
Tokenize();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

see here `$encrypted_data = "acAx/CwWGCURIhwf7gIw36TFmXoGFrFa5l9hCgcGEW4/mVQAAzZuT4XRjktb7XR0sAthHTuSPYegNYUy7g1stP+ypfVBcH0hNiI72N22yy3WYp0VUfAKDp33HBgUVQwg0TWAenRSNbUwC0Qv49E5bubYo4YBnERWi4JNLJZPlEQUfjMovvWQsQdFHd7U79XJZnZQdW92CKFDrTX8bCS4/n0LDEEVBILJGBnjnvKOQjQarsX8OuU6/73qpy36f9Gz3+X6IRfRhVbINNV0Seii6qSXT03NyvbERDsU/CiOrZ1tY0RuiKh4rsvCfPYrX2h67ZZ7nzrz0DeV+BYyo0e06A=="`
i need the cipher text i got using when i pressed the submit button..I need the statement in php to retieve this cipher text into the variable `$encrypted_data` (as of now I have given a standalone data there)

Also there is someproblem in the php section where some payloads are being sent to a webservice using JSON,but I dont seem getting a response( ie the token which is been sent bak as a response from the webservice wehn i sent my token_id,api key and encrypted data

can someone help in making this code working?Im actaully new to php and Im doing all this with the help of their documentation and online steps.Do bear this long question,im a begineer,so I have to present this compeletly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CURL request is failing completely you should have an error in [curl_error($ch)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) or if it returns a strange result you can get information about the last request made using [curl_info($ch)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) so some combination of the two should help you work out where an error might be occurring.

Comment: See im getting the converted json `echo "Step1 done... ";
 echo $json;` but after that line im getting "Error" that is its not either getting to cURL or What can be the problem over there?

Comment: this is my output Step1 done...
{"TokenExID":"7639945321063574","APIKey":"0za2fOfdWU5OKYwMBnTH","EncryptedData":"false","TokenScheme":4}

Result is 
JSON Result is 
Error Message:

Comment: Before `//decode result` you could try `if(curl_error($ch)){ $jsonResult['Error'] = curl_error($ch); }` to trap a curl error, such as the request timing out.

Comment: thanks oddEssay i will try that will let know after i test it

Comment: ok Im getting `Step1 done... {"TokenExID":"7639945321063574","APIKey":"0za2fOfdWU5OKYwMBnTH","Data":"acAx\/CwWGCURIhwf7gIw36TFmXoGFrFa5l9hCgcGEW4\/mVQAAzZuT4XRjktb7XR0sAthHTuSPYegNYUy7g1stP+ypfVBcH0hNiI72N22yy3WYp0VUfAKDp33HBgUVQwg0TWAenRSNbUwC0Qv49E5bubYo4YBnERWi4JNLJZPlEQUfjMovvWQsQdFHd7U79XJZnZQdW92CKFDrTX8bCS4\/n0LDEEVBILJGBnjnvKOQjQarsX8OuU6\/73qpy36f9Gz3+X6IRfRhVbINNV0Seii6qSXT03NyvbERDsU\/CiOrZ1tY0RuiKh4rsvCfPYrX2h67ZZ7nzrz0DeV+BYyo0e06A==","TokenScheme":4}
Result is this 
Error Message: couldn't connect to host' in my browser.what probably can be the problem.

Comment: It gives an error message as "Error Message: couldn't connect to host"..I also tried this using a REST console extension using chrome and it returned me the result I wanted.But while I try this using manual curl programming,this is the error what im getting.Its pretty sure that its working untill the encode statement where the datats are encoded as json,but after that it cant initiate the curl.I cant really figure whats going wrong,please do help me solve this.Im a begineer in php so finding its hard to go on without any help.

Comment: The error "couldn't connect to host" is pretty self explanatory - A quick Google for that message will turn up dozens of StackOverflow answers on just that particular issue, the gist of which is you probably need to open up https for outbound traffic on your firewall.